# My cod: ghosts multiplayer keeps crashing. What do I do?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-ghosts

In the middle of any match in cod: ghosts (multiplayer) it crashes and says "You must be signed in to Xbox Live to play Xbox Live matches" and I was just playing 5 seconds ago. Please help me, this is really starting to irritate me now. I have it on Xbox 360

Comment: have you pressed the xbox button and confirmed your still signed in and that your connection didn't just drop out?

Comment: Running WiFi, or LAN?

Comment: Any other devices on the network(mobile, pc, phone hub)?

Comment: Try FFA, it's less players. What does it say at the bottom right area where it states your NAT type; (Open,Moderate,Strict)? When you go to search for a match, press "X" "Square" for PS# users. It will have your search preferences, are they set to "Any", "Normal", "Best"?

Answer (score 1):

If this issue "suddenly" starts happening to you it can often be explained by server issues out of your control.

When this error occurs you should check the Xbox Live Service Status - Just google this term so you can find the localised version of the page.  This can indicate that there is an issue with the services.  The details given range from directly naming the game as having match making issues or something vague regarding service issues.

You can also check the Xbox Live forums.  If you see plenty of new threads detailing the error over the past hour or so then you can see that the issue is common.

The solution to this problem is to do something else for a couple of hours.  Go outside as the graphics are usually better.